# Download Zip File From FTP in Memory and Unzip it

Tags: python, ftp, zip

I'm trying to create a function that downloads a file from a FTP in memory and returns it. In this case I am trying download a zip file and unzip it without writing the file locally, but I am getting the following error:

```
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
```

Here is my current code:

```
from io import BytesIO
from ftplib import FTP_TLS

def download_from_ftp(fp):
    """
    Retrieves file from a ftp
    """
    ftp_host = 'some ftp url'
    ftp_user = 'ftp username'
    ftp_pass = 'ftp password'

    with FTP_TLS(ftp_host) as ftp:
        ftp.login(user=ftp_user, passwd=ftp_pass)
        ftp.prot_p()
        with BytesIO() as download_file:
            ftp.retrbinary('RETR ' + fp, download_file.write)
            download_file.seek(0)
            return download_file
```

And here is my code that tries and unzips the file:

```
import zipfile
from ftp import download_from_ftp

ftp_file = download_from_ftp('ftp zip file path')
with zipfile.ZipFile(ftp_file, 'r') as zip_ref:
    # do some stuff with files in the zip
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By instantiating `BytesIO` as a context manager, it closes the file handle upon exit, so `download_file` no longer has an open file handle when it is returned to the caller.

You can simply assign the instantiated `BytesIO` object a variable for return instead. Change:

```
with BytesIO() as download_file:
```

to:

```
download_file = BytesIO()
```

and dedent the block.